# Set cxDateEdit Time

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Is there a way to set cxDateEdit's time to 0.00.00 ? Now,it always fetches the current time.
I want the time to 00. Thought I do not need time, even if I remove it, my date still takes time into the account.

Comment: Don't know this control, but generally you can "cut-off" the time portion with `SomeDateTimeVariable := Trunc(DateTime);` or better yet with `DateOf` function.

Comment: You can cut time,set its property to date only but time, it's still present. Need to reset the counter to "0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
DateUtils.DateOf(cxDateEdit1.Date);
```

The [`DateOf`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.DateOf) function as described in the reference:

> Strips the time portion from a TDateTime value. Call DateOf to convert
>   a TDateTime value to a TDateTime value that includes only the date
>   information (sets the time portion to 0, which means midnight).

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the display of the time by setting the Properties in the Object inspector. More specifically, Expand the `Properties` property and set `Kind = ckDate`

Comment: ShowTime and SaveTime also to false?

Comment: @user3181689 SaveTime set to False as Ravaut123 mentioned.

Comment: does not work....date still relies on time.It looks like it does not but actually it does.Every time you select date the current time is applied to that date. It does not matter if you save it,show it, or not.

Comment: @user3181689 What version of DevExpress are you using? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: 2013.1.2   I need to calculate day sharp (from-to 24 hours exactly).I cant have any other time.

Comment: @user3181689 I suggest you contact DevExpress and take it up with them. The behaviour you're describing is consistent with the standard Win32 TDateTimePicker (which has been a known issue for over 10 years), but the TcxDateEdit works perfectly for me (I tried it on the latest version and an old 3.48 version.